# Can I do StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(System.in)?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer, system.in

In Java, can I do

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(System.in);
```

?

I am wondering if I can expect to collect the input stream as a sting like that or is there a better way of getting the user input converted to a string before I can use it as an argument for my string tokenizer?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I am working from a school computer that won't let me test my code right now. I will need to get to my own computer or one that has admin privileges for me to try my code. So, please bear with me.

Comment: There must be some way you can test code...or [read about it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: why don't you try it and see

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I just added an update in response to @Ingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that because the constructor for StringTokenizer() requires an argument of type `java.lang.String`, but System.in is of type `java.io.InputStream`.

A better way of converting user input to a String would be to use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter name: ");
String name = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter age: ");
String age = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(name + " is " + age + "years old");
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I see why the Scanner can work with System.in but not the StringTokenizer.

Comment: To reach my goal, I am attempting this:

`BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String userInputString = userInput.readLine();`
Then I pass `userInputString` as an argument to my  `StringTokenizer`
Please tell me this is not ridiculous!

Comment: @Alain no problem, I've included an example of using a Scanner to get the users name.

Comment: @Alain It depends on what kind of input you are expecting, but using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is generally easier because it has methods such as `hasNext()` which tells you whether there is input to scan, and `useDelimiter()` which allows you to tokenize the input.

Comment: Thanks, @Jason. I've been experimenting with `Scanner` for the first time today. Well, since yesterday actually since it's past midnight now.